# How to convert PNG image to Array?

Tags: actionscript-3, image, arrays

I'm trying to make a tile-based AS3 game that uses PNG images as the base for maps that loads them from the library and converts the data to an array with each pixel of data being an individual tile. Essentially, if I had a 128x128 pixel PNG with say, green pixels being converted to "GRASS" in my array, I could then cycle through the array and add tiles to the map movieclip accordingly.

I've looked at the ByteArray class and I can't seem to decode the data into a usable format. If anyone has a solution to do this, please let me know.

Comment: what have you tried so far? how has it not worked as expected? or are you expecting the community to do your work for you? Do read the [faq] to see what kind of questions we like answering and what we don't. :) oh, and welcome to StackOverflow :D

Comment: Just curious, but is this question inspired by something Notch has done?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: I tried using the ByteArray class in an attempt to output a string of characters that I could manually convert to a visible map onscreen, but I could not find a method of decoding PNGs that worked properly.
@ Adam: No, as I will be creating maps quite large, a visual representation would be the easiest to create and manage well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) class seems like what you are looking for. Make sure the images in your library have there own class name, and that it's base class is Bitmap (in properties), then create an instance of the image, and loop through its bitmap pixel data using [getPixel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel%28%29).

Something like this:

```
var image:Bitmap = new MyBMP();
var bmd:BitmapData = image.bitmapData;

for(var y:int=0; y < bmd.height; ++y)
{
    for(var x:int=0; x < bmd.width; ++x)
    {
        var pixelValue:uint = bmd.getPixel(x, y);
        trace(pixelValue.toString(16));
        // Test if the pixelValue matches the colour you want.
    }           
}
```

Just a note, make sure to use [getPixel32](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#getPixel32%28%29) if you are use alpha channel.